# Can't get ng-dirty to form input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a form which defined in directives.js file. I can create `input` by adding new record in database. I have problem setting one input field to `ng-dirty` from `ng-pristine` because i don't know how to write `ng-model` name with 3 dots in scope. Everything else works fine. The reason i want to do it, it's because when i give radio button value and after click, it gives this value to specific input but problem is, it doesn't modify input and state from `ng-prisitne` to `ng-dirty` doesn't change. That's why it doesn't give input actual value and i can't save radio button value to database, of course after typing something it saves value + new typed value. So maybe there is other way to figure this out. Would love to have any other suggestions.

Here is directive code from directives.js. (Not whole)

```
html = '<div><ng-form name="eavform">' + html + element.html() + '</ng-form></div>';

var newElem = angular.element(html);

var attrElem = input ? newElem.find(input) : newElem;

attrElem.attr('ng-model', 'vals.eav.' + config.ID);
attrElem.addClass('form-control');
attrElem.attr('placeholder', config.description);
attrElem.attr('name', fieldName);
```

TPL file code where inputs and radio buttons are showed.

```
<eav-formatted config="[[ eavFieldsHandle.adrese.toJson() ]]">
    <eav-field></eav-field>
</eav-formatted>

<input type="radio" name="btn" id="radio-1" ng-click="addText(); eavform.vals.eav.13.$setDirty()">
```

Controller file

```
app.controller('KamejaCheckoutController', function ($scope, $http)
{
    $scope.vals = {};
    $scope.addText = function()
    {
    $scope.vals.eav.13 = "now I'm dirty";
    }
});
```

[image: Browser code]

Comment: PS. Have tried removing classes and adding new ones. `$('input[name="eav_13"]').removeClass();`  
`$('input[name="eav_13"]').addClass('form-control ng-dirty ng-valid ng-valid-required');`
For specific input this works but for form it displays copied form.

Comment: Can you add plunker?

Comment: That would be very problematic, because all files are in server. But i will try it.

Comment: Here is a plunker with bit of code. http://plnkr.co/edit/wsrBuzKZ0ode8dRHR2NU?p=preview

Comment: Updated: Added picture of inspect element code from browser.

Comment: Why you dont call $setPristine / $setDirty for whole form?

Comment: the setDirty applies to the whole form, not just one input element. "evaForm.vals.13 does not make sense to me. in your controller you have it exposed on the scope.

Comment: try this <input type="radio" name="btn" id="radio-1" ng-click="addText(); eavform.$setDirty()">

Comment: Check this updated plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/oguV4PhlV8BHm4R6uK6Q?p=preview you can see when you type into the text box the form is set to dirty

Comment: Tried to do this to whole form still nothing. Form doesn't change to [modified] state.